# Why is the output of the Java code below "adb", and not "abd"?

Tags: java, exception, callstack

I am trying to understand what the exception code below prints when run. I know what it prints, "adb", but I don't understand why that is printed.

```
public class MyClass {
static String str = "a";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClass().method1();
    System.out.println(str);
}

void method1() {
    try {
        method2();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        str += "b";
    }
}

void method2() throws Exception {
    try {
        method3();
        str += "c";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    finally {
        str += "d";
    }
    method3();
    str += "e";
}

void method3() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}
}
```

When method3() is called, it throws a new exception, which is caught by method2(), also throwing a new exception, which is caught by method1(), adding "b" to the string, and then the finally block executes in method2(), adding "d"? So why is it not "abd", but "adb"?

Comment: The `finally` block in `method2` is executed before it returns, so the `d` is appended first.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with a list of what exceptions are thrown and in what order to help me visualize it? Thanks!

Comment: _When method3() is called, it throws a new exception, which is caught by method2(), also throwing a new exception, then the finally block executes in method2(), adding "d", then the exception is caught by method1(), adding "b" to the string_

Comment: Will the _finally_  block always be executed after the try/catch block within its own method, even if an exception is thrown in the catch block in its own method?

Comment: @coolcow - yes, that is the point of finally - it always executes on completion of the try/catch block.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "a"
```

now `method1()` is called

now `method2()` is called in `method1()`

now `method3()` is called in `method2()`
and throws exception, the exception is caught in `method2()` and `str+= "c"` is not executed. Instead a new exception is thrown and the `finally` clause executes:

```
str += d
```

method3() is called again, throws exception which in turn is caught in method1() adding

```
str += b
```

Here we are.